# Specifying path of CSV file in an SQL script (H2 database)

Tags: h2

I have an H2 database file which is created by importing tables from CSV files, using the CSVREAD command provided by H2 (described here: http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv). The CSV files are just tables in text format, and are generated by Perl scripts. Every time I generate new versions of the CSV files, I have to delete the database tables and import the CSV files again to the database, using the CSVREAD command. This database is to be used by a webserver. But, instead of uploading the database file (which gets too big), I prefer to upload the CSV files to the server, and then execute a script (with the RUNSCRIPT command or from the command line, using the H2 RunScript tool), so that the database tables are generated inside the server.

My problem is that, to use the CSVREAD command inside a script, I have to specify the absolute path of the CSV files. Instead of writing the absolute path inside the script file, it would be convenient to be able to pass the absolute path as an argument to the RUNSCRIPT command, so that I don't have to hardcode it inside the script. Then, in the script file, I would just write a placeholder that would get replaced by the argument value. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you use a path relative to the current working directory (the directory where you started the process)? That is, `./csv/data.txt`. Or a path relative to the current user home directory (`~/csv/data.csv`)?

Comment: @ThomasMueller: It would be possible to put the CSV files together with the .class files, but the web server (openshift) has a data directory which is specified by an environment variable, so I put the CSV files there. Since I'm a beginner, I'm not sure whether it would be good practice to put the CSV files inside the WAR file.

Comment: CSV files with .class files: H2 supports reading from Java resources from the classpath, would that be an option? Just use the path `classpath:/org/acme/test.csv`. Also see the docs about the [Pluggable File System](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system) (but I don't expect you to write a file system :-)

Comment: Using environment variables or system properties within scripts is possible, but quite tricky (you would probably need a user defined function, and then build the path inside the script).